# IText sharp break the words with Pashto char

Tags: c#, pdf, unicode, itext

I am using Itextsharp to write data to pdf templates. others Unicode char is alright. but we have eight char in our Native language like (ژ،ړ،څ،ڼ). when these char come between the words, itextsharp break the words there and this char write individually. I am also use Unicode  fonts, but No good result. below is my code.

```
public ActionResult GeneratePDF()
        {
            var filename = "~/PdfTemplates/Individual4.pdf";
            string file = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath(filename));

            MemoryStream masterStream = new MemoryStream();

            PdfCopyFields copy = new PdfCopyFields(masterStream);
            PdfReader tmpReader = new PdfReader(file);
            MemoryStream tmpStream = new MemoryStream();
            tmpStream.Position = 0;
        PdfStamper tmpOutStamper = new PdfStamper(tmpReader, tmpStream);
        AcroFields fields = tmpOutStamper.AcroFields;
        var arialFontPath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Fonts), Server.MapPath("~/fonts/Pashto Nazo.TTF"));
        var arialBaseFont = BaseFont.CreateFont(arialFontPath, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
        fields.AddSubstitutionFont(arialBaseFont);
        string tt = "لړم،څپلۍ، کوڼ نړۍ ژمۍ";
       // byte[] utf8Bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(tt);

        fields.SetField("TaxPayerName",  tt);


        tmpOutStamper.Writer.CloseStream = false;
        tmpOutStamper.FormFlattening = true;
        tmpOutStamper.Close();
        byte[] buf = tmpStream.ToArray();
        PdfReader nwPgReader = new PdfReader(buf);
        copy.AddDocument(nwPgReader);


       copy.Close();
        byte[] ss = masterStream.ToArray();



        return File(ss, "application/pdf");
    }
```

and below is snapshot of template
[image]

Comment: And the question is..?